# How to remove a subdirectory from the middle of a url in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have an issue where I am trying to use nginx to remove sub directory from the middle of a URL.

I have:
`https://example.com/pub/static/version1532296276/frontend/Alothemes/default/ar_KW/requirejs/require.min.js`

I want to rewrite it to:
`https://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/default/ar_KW/requirejs/require.min.js`

How would I use nginx url rewriting to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a rule like this:

```
rewrite ^/pub/static/version\d+/(.*)$ /pub/static/$1 last;
```

See the following documentation to see how to write rules for nginx:

- [How to create NGINX Rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: where i can add this rule in nginx file configuration ?

Comment: You would put this into the configuration file for the website in question. It would be somewhere in the nginx folder.

Comment: I know this but I mean what is a location in the file I can add this rule to it ?

Comment: anywhere within the `server` braces